# How to subtract consecutive strings with respect to another string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, subtraction

I have a list of strings as follows

```
['ENST00000641515.2', 'ENSG00000186092.6', 'OTTHUMG00000001094.4', 
'OTTHUMT00000003223.4', 'OR4F5', '202', 'OR4F5', '2618', 'UTR5', '1', '60', 
'CDS', '61', '1041', 'UTR3', '1042', '2618', '', 'ENST00000335137.4', 
'ENSG00000186092.6', 'OTTHUMG00000001094.4', '', '', 'OR4F5', '201', 'OR4F5',
 '1054', 'UTR5', '1', '36']
```

I want to iterate through this list, and if string is 'UTR5', i want to subtract the two consecutive strings after that from each other(latter from the previous). The subtracting values should get added and finally print out the answer.

Example:
after first 'UTR5' there is 1 and 60. So i want to subtract 60 - 1.  in second 'UTR5' it is 36-1.
Final answer should get printed as 94

I'm new to python, can somebody suggest me a script. Thanks in advance. Original list is huge. I have given a shorter version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lst = ['ENST00000641515.2', 'ENSG00000186092.6', 'OTTHUMG00000001094.4',
       'OTTHUMT00000003223.4', 'OR4F5', '202', 'OR4F5', '2618', 'UTR5', '1', '60',
       'CDS', '61', '1041', 'UTR3', '1042', '2618', '', 'ENST00000335137.4',
       'ENSG00000186092.6', 'OTTHUMG00000001094.4', '', '', 'OR4F5', '201', 'OR4F5',
       '1054', 'UTR5', '1', '36']

total = 0
for i, x in enumerate(lst):
    if lst[i] == 'UTR5':
        total += (int(lst[i + 2]) - int(lst[i + 1]))

print(total)
```

take a look at [`enumerate`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumerate-in-python/) usage in for loops over iterables.

Note that it is assumed that the indexes `i+1` and `i+2` are integers..

Answer (score 1):

you can do that easily with [`numpy.argwhere`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html)

```
>>> data = np.array(['ENST00000641515.2', 'ENSG00000186092.6', 'OTTHUMG00000001094.4',
       'OTTHUMT00000003223.4', 'OR4F5', '202', 'OR4F5', '2618', 'UTR5',
       '1', '60', 'CDS', '61', '1041', 'UTR3', '1042', '2618', '',
       'ENST00000335137.4', 'ENSG00000186092.6', 'OTTHUMG00000001094.4',
       '', '', 'OR4F5', '201', 'OR4F5', '1054', 'UTR5', '1', '36'])
>>> x = np.argwhere(data == "UTR5") + 1
>>> y = np.argwhere(data == "UTR5") + 2
>>> diff = data[y].astype(np.int) - data[x].astype(np.int)
>>> diff.sum()
94
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by zipping shifted versions of the list:

```
total = sum(int(c) - int(b) for a, b, c in zip(lst, lst[1:], lst[2:]) if a == "UTR5")
```